# JavaScript summing of textboxes

Tags: javascript, dynamic, textbox

I could really your help! I need to sum a dynamic amount of textboxes but my JavaScript knowledge is way to week to accomplish this. Anyone could help me out? I want the function to print the sum in the p-tag named inptSum.

Here's a function and the html code:

```
function InputSum() {
    ...
}

<table id="tbl">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">
            <span>June</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="month_0" type="text" value="0" id="month_0" onchange="InputSum()" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">
            <span>July</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="month_1" type="text" value="0" id="month_1" onchange="InputSum()" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">
            <span>August</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="month_2" type="text" value="0" id="month_2"  onchange="InputSum()" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">
            <span>September</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="month_3" type="text" value="0" id="month_3" onchange="InputSum()" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<p id="inputSum"></p>
```

Comment: How do you know how many boxes you have ?

Comment: @SaintGerbil I don't, I suppose I'll have to count the ones that begins with "month_".

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson Sorry, the values entered in the textboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little jQuery, you could do it quite easily, using the [attribute starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector. We then loop over them, parses their values into integers and sum them up. Something like this:

```
function InputSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    $('input[id^="month_"]').each(function () {
        sum += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    });
    $("#inputSum").text(sum);
}
```

You could even get rid of the onchange attributes on each input if you modify the code to something like this:

```
$(function () {
    var elms = $('input[id^="month_"]');
    elms.change(function() {
        var sum = 0;
        elms.each(function () {
            sum += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
        });
        $("#inputSum").text(sum);
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you included the jQuery library? Do you get any JS-errors? This should fire everytime any of the inputs are changed, like your `onchanged=""` attribute.

Comment: Yes, I added the library. No errors. I but a breakpoint inside of it and it's never fired.

Comment: Now I got it firing but only at page load. Not when text is changed.

Comment: @PeterSaverman Sorry my bad. I called `onchange()` which actually should be `change()`. Updated my answer. Hope that should fix it for you.

Comment: I just tried pasting it into a new document and then it worked like a charm. Thanks! Just gonna have to figure out what is wrong with my orirginal document. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
function InputSum() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); 
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) { 
        if(inputs[i].id.indexOf("month_") == 0) 
            alert(inputs[i].value); 
    }
}
```

Comment: That was quick, Matei. Two things: 1.The values are being added on a row instead of summed up. Maybe I'll find out how to do this myself. 2. It's not always known how many textboxes there are. How can I count the once named month_*?

Comment: I've edited my answer so now can be as many inputs as you want but the ids should begin with `month_`

Comment: Hmm. That one is not working for me. All I did was replacing the old one.

Answer (score 0):

```
function InputSum() {
   var month_0=document.getElementById("month_0").value;// get value from textbox
  var month_1=document.getElementById("month_1").value;
  var month_2=document.getElementById("month_2").value;
   var month_3=document.getElementById("month_3").value;
   // check number Can be omitted the

   alert(month_0+month_1+month_2+month_3);//show result 
}
```

Comment: It's not always four textboxes, although they're always named month_*.